# Shnayim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two hundred two?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Please don't tell me this one also has to do with Orla mixtures.

Comment: העורלה מעלה את הכלאיים, והכלאיים את העורלה, והעורלה את העורלה.  כיצד:  סאה עורלה שנפלה למאתיים, ואחר כך נפלה סאה ועוד עורלה, או סאה ועוד של כלאי הכרם--זו היא שהעורלה מעלה את הכלאיים, והכלאיים את העורלה, והעורלה את העורלה. Orlah 2:3

Comment: YDK, I take it back. Go ahead and put this in as an answer, please.

Comment: OK, but I'm still working on Orlah and 203

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the exile of the Jewish People in Egypt, they refined and elevated 202 of the "sparks of holiness" that Hashem scattered throughout the world. This is alluded to by the Torah's expression (Ex. 12:38) that "a great mixture" (ערב רב, the last word of which equals 202) accompanied them out of Egypt.

(Cited in many Kabbalistic and Chassidic works. [This article](http://www.haoros.com/Archive/index.asp?kovetz=1001&cat=7&haoro=3) provides a source that traces it to the Arizal.)

Answer (score 2):

In Chutz L'Aretz we do not eat Chometz for **appx** 202 hours each year.

8 days x 24 hours = 192 hours

We stop eating Chometz **appx** 9 actual hours (although it is based on Zemanios, for clarity in this answer I am basing it on actual hours) before Shekia

We do not start eating Chometz for close to an hour after Shekiya on Motzai Pesach

Total = 202 hours

Comment: I thought the Erev Pesach deadlines were based on sha'ot zemaniot. Who says that they aren't? Also, couldn't some people make Havdalah 42 minutes after sunset on Motzaei Pesach and immediately start eating chametz (purchased immediately from a non-Jewish store)?

Comment: It is dependent on Zemanios, however in actual hours it ends up in most areas of the US being appx 9 hours. Regarding the 42 minutes, many people do not end up Davening till closer to an hour, and even if they Daven earlier till they get to the store, till they purchase takes time. I know my Rav says that it takes him till at least 60 minutes after Shekiya to purchase back the Chometz from the non Jew.

Comment: OK, so your statement is a practical one rather than a strictly Halachic one. That's fine.

Answer (score 2):

This Mishna (Orlah 2:3) has different approaches, but for the purpose of this question:

If one part Orlah falls into 200 parts of heter, that 201st part becomes heter to the extent that a 202nd+ part is also nullified, so long as the plus part is 1/200th of a part or less. [one approach of the Tiferes Yisrael -see text above that this halacha applies to kilayim as well.]

[Alternatively: 1 part orla falls into 199 parts heter to make 200, then 1+ part of neta revai (defined here as 'orlah') or kilayim fall in, the latter 1+ of neta revai or kilayim combine with the heter to nullify the orla, and (acc. to R' Yehoshua that only needs a 199+:1 ratio, the 1 part orlah can combine with the heter to nullify the kilayim.]